# Migrating a service from its v2 address to a new v3 one

Tags: configuration, onion-services

I'm running a bitcoin node behind a v2 onion address. I'd like to migrate its traffic to a different, v3 address.

Is there a way that my peers can be notified of such a change so they learn that myv2addess.onion and myv3address.onion are actually the same machine? Or do I have to just bring the myv3address.onion online and wait for traffic to come?

Answer (score 0):

I realize that the question was asked about a year ago, but I will respond hoping that it would be useful for someone given the ongoing [v2 onion services deprecation](https://blog.torproject.org/v2-deprecation-timeline).

Assuming you already created a version 3 address i.e in `torrc` add these lines:

`HiddenServiceDir /full/path/to/your/new/v3/directory/`

`HiddenServicePort <virtual port> <target-address>:<target-port>`

You might want to keep running your version 2 service until it is deprecated to provide a transition path to your users. Add this line to the configuration block of your version 2 service:

`HiddenServiceVersion 2`

Now you can advertise your new v3 onion address with [Onion-Location](https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/advanced/onion-location/) or maybe add a small note on your v2 onion service.